# TabBar in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I need help in React Navigation when I create a tab bar  like I have button home and I want to access another screen in the Home with show tab bar inside it to keep selected on the Home icon.

[First Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gabX.jpg)

[Second Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM3pT.png)

I want show tabBar with continue select Home button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem by A stack navigator for each tab.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/?fbclid=IwAR071_HAYPP9NYGbVHq88j1ZssyBn8226Qnne_PzUdGdIM56XrVD5shU10c#a-stack-navigator-for-each-tab

Answer (score -1):

I think you should have a variable that would keep track of the home page and when you are on it and thus provide the styling you need on the homepage icon....and when you are in the second screen it should be still be set to true so nothing changes

Comment: Be more specific.  What does "a variable" mean?  Is it in a component's state?  How is it shared across routes/components?